# Why the old MySQL user password still works from a different server?

Tags: mysql, sql, passwords, devops

I have a server that MySQL is installed on. Also, phpMyAdmin is installed on the same server. From the other side, I have another server (same network) where the backend codes (APIs) are located.

I've changed the mysql user password this way:

```
ALTER USER myuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Now, the phpMyAdmin works with `mypass` (new password), but the backend server still works with the old mysql user credential:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=<server ip>
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=user_name
DB_PASSWORD="<old password>     -- this
```

Why? And how can I make that mysql user accessible from everywhere by the new password?

Comment: @Fang yes. Isn't the issue related to using `localhost` in `myuser@localhost` ?

Comment: @Fang Why would they need to do that? That's only needed if you modify the `mysql.user` table directly instead of using `ALTER USER`.

Comment: Execute  `select user,host from mysql_user where user='myuser'`. There is likely a second user with hostname=% or IP address which still has the old password.